# What's the difference between "ABC" and string("ABC") in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code snippet...

```
for(char c: "ABC") cout << c << endl;
for(char c: string("ABC")) cout << c << endl;
```

The second one works fine. But's first one behaves different in different environment. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"behaves different in different environment"*?

Comment: In my machine, all outputs are garbage. On coderforces, first line prints A B C [some garbage]. On ideone, it prints A B C [blank].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"ABC"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with type `const char[4]`, i.e. an array containing 4 `char`s including the terminating null character `'\0'`. `for(char c: "ABC") cout << c << endl;` would output all the 4 elements.

`string("ABC")` is of type `std::string` constructed to contain only 3 elements, `for(char c: string("ABC")) cout << c << endl;` would output the 3 elements, `'A'`, `'B'`, and `'C'`.

Comment: The language/library does not guarantee any predictable output when a non-printable character is passed to `cout`. The OP's confusion might stem from that.